# How to Audit any change in Permission?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, audit

Is there any way how to know "Who did change the permission on users"

Like:

- who give read permission or owner on a database for a user?

Using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included).

Comment: Please see this post. I think [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/track-grant-permission-on-tables?rq=1) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sys.database_permissions for all the permissions of all objects in database including who did grant permission.

Comment: EXECUTE AS USER = 'UserName';  
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('YourSchema.TablaName', 'OBJECT')   
    ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name ;    
REVERT;  
GO